# SQL Server and updating windows firewall rules

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, trigger

Any ideas how should I proceed if I would like to  update the firewall rules (essentially add ip-s to existing firewall rule).

The step of exporting ip-s to text file and then using command line to add/edit rules seems like a extra  step that requires some sort of automation as well.

Basically a ban list - it would currently only ban the account itself but I would like to use the associated ip to add it to the firewall rule whenever a new ban is added (trigger to check the update is a way to go) - but I'm not sure how to incorporate firewall update with SQL Server.

Would a trigger allow to run a command line command line function lets say basic "ping google.com" to start and test if it works.

like

```
BEGIN
SELECT i.ip FROM inserted AS i
INNER JOIN deleted AS d
ON i.ip = d.ip
"now do the  command line tricks and pass the i.ip as a parameter like " ping i.ip
END
```

So how should i proceed about the command line part?

SQL Server 2008 R2 sp2  windows 2008 server.

Comment: Sounds like a case for Powershell to affect the OS change. xp_cmdshell might get it done but I can't recall firewall command line controls myself. Lots of PS wizards here to help out though.

Comment: yeh the firewall cmd line part isnt a problem, im just wondering how do i get access to them, powershell would work too i guess.
xp_cmdshell - but can i pass a value to it from SELECT ?

Comment: Are you trying to add/modify firewall rules on the SQL server itself, or on a remote server?